# C# set winform key preview highest priority

Tags: c#, winforms

here i'm trying to make a program that when i press the keyboard "F6", it would auto. move the cursor to a position and click. I tested my program on desktop, it works. But when I go into a game and press F6, it doesn't seem to be working. Some people work, some people does not. I was thinking is there any like keypreview priority that I can do?

```
 private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Stop();
        if (IsKeyPushedDown(Keys.F6))
        {
            if (auth == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("请先登录");
                timer1.Start();
                return;
            }

            SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
            //Original
            if (rdbtnoriginal.Checked == true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                hack();
            }
        }
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Here I use a timer tick, I got the code from online, so when I'm not focusing on the form and press F6 it will trigger the event. But some people go into the game and press F6 it doesn't work

Comment: The only way to ensure you always see the keystroke is to implement a low level keyboard hook via WH_KEYBOARD_LL.  Search for it...you'll find tons of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Winforms relies on the window being focused for key messages to register in the application (if the window isn't focused, the IsKeyPushedDown won't register any keys as the window hasn't recieved the keypressed message in the background.  you may want to use the input features from DXInput or OpenGL, or have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18890/NET-Hookless-Key-logger-Advanced-Keystroke-Mining. there are probably other libraries/pieces of code.  Google is your friend, Key logging is probably your best search term.

Comment: I have used something call "async" which means you can trigger it while the form is not focused, i tested it on two of my laptop, they work perfectly fine while not focus, but on someone else's computer they didn't work. But thank you very much, i will take a look at the link you posted. Regards

Comment: Some games can effect How windows responds to keyboard/mouse input. some technologies can take exclusive control over a device (this is why some SST software/button scripting tools don't work on all games.

Just another thing to consider :) hope you resolve your issue

Comment: I tried using lowlevel keyboard hook. It works while the form is not focus. But while i'm in game it still won't work. Is there any priority for the lowlevel keyboard hook? I tried to make two programs that used lowlevel keyboard hook. Apparently the second one that opens will overwrite the lowlevel keyboard hook on the first one opens.